# Button click works on second click only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button and a div under it, the button must show this div onclick, i wrote the function and everything is fine, but it works only on second click and i can't figure out why, here is my code:

```js
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showDiv()">Show div</button>

<div id="myDiv">
test
test
test
test 
test
test 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting CSS style does not pervade to `x.style.display` so when you click the first time `x.style.display` actually equals `""`, so it hits your else block and sets the `style.display` to `none`, 2nd time and it hits the first branch of the conditional and shows your div.

Either use `computedStyle` to grab the actual style, or, this would be a little easier using classes.

JS:

`function show () {
  var x = document.querySelector('#myDiv')
  x.classList.toggle('show')
}`

CSS:

`.show {
  display: 'block';
}`

`Classlist` is supported for all modern browsers but some really old ones will struggle with it, although good polyfills exist.

Answer (score 3):

To get the value that you apply via a stylesheet (or block) you need to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle). `document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display` can only read inline styles.

```js
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    if ( window.getComputedStyle(x, null).getPropertyValue("display") === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showDiv()">Show div</button>

<div id="myDiv">
test
test
test
test 
test
test 
</div>
```

Comment: Downvoter care to comment on the problem? Is this answer somehow not useful? Sour grapes I guess.

Comment: I don't know who downvoted but its not a particularly helpful answer, whilst it *does* answer the question there is a better solution readily available that doesn't rely on slow apis. There are also 2 identical answers that were posted *before* yours.

Comment: @MattStyles I won't debate the helpfulness, however the two answers posted before mine are not identical, and prior to their owners editing them, neither contained a reference to `getComputedStyle()`

Answer (score 1):

You have set the style in css.So the value of `x.style.display` is not none initially.it wolud be empty.So set that style initially. or use `getComputedStyle` to get the  CSS rule

```js
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
 
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showDiv()">Show div</button>

<div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">
test
test
test
test 
test
test 
</div>
```

if the element's display is being inherited or being specified by a CSS rule, compute the style using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

```js
function showDiv() {
        var x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
   
      
        if (getComputedStyle(x, null).display === 'none') {
            x.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            x.style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
```

```css
#myDiv{
      display: none;
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showDiv()">Show div</button>

    <div id="myDiv">
    test
    test
    test
    test 
    test
    test 
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you but i already have it displayed none in the css file, why do i have to put as an inline style?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is that `x.style.display` corresponds with the `display` property attached inline to your element. It ignores your CSS selector, which means that `x.style.display === 'none'` is false the first time you run your function.

Inlining `display:none` would fix your problem :

```
<div id="myDiv">...</div>      → → →      <div id="myDiv" style="display:none;">...</div>
```

However, that's not the recommended approach here. A better way to achieve the desired result, would be to toggle a class :

```js
document.getElementById('myButton').addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button id="myButton" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Show div</button>
<div id="myDiv" class="hidden">test test test test test test</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because div doesn't have display in style. You can add it manually:

```js
function showDiv() {
    var x = document.getElementById('myDiv');
    if (x.style.display === 'none') {
        x.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        x.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
#myDiv{
display: none;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="showDiv()">Show div</button>

<div id="myDiv" style='display:none'>
test
test
test
test 
test
test 
</div>
```

Comment: thank you but i already have it displayed none in the css, why do i have to put as an inline style?

Comment: like: `<div id="myDiv" style='display:none'>`. You can see it in my answer.